# Gradle - Shared project dependency as a jar

Tags: java, spring, build, jar, gradle

I have 3 projects

Webapp1 and Webapp2 and a 3rd project i called SharedProject

Both webapps1,2 are using the sharedproject classes.

I would like to include the sharedproject as a jar in both of them.

In eclipse i could set for each project that it depends on the 3rd project and on every war file i export it will attach the jar automagically.

Is there a similar easy way with gradle? I couldnt find any tutorials for this specific concept.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the shared project as a dependency in the other projects should do it, e.g.:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':SharedProject')
}
```